# What does `npx .` do when executed for the first time in some directory?

Tags: npx

I'm making some experiments with node, npx and npm using the "bin" property of npm packages, so I made a folder with two files

- package.json
- index.js

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "bin": "./index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And the index.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

console.log("hello, world!")
```

Now if I run `npx .` to test if everything is working, npx says

```
Need to install the following packages:
  file:
Ok to proceed? (y)
```

I answer `y`, then the command is installed and executed, so `hello, world!` is printed on the console

But now if I change the file name from *`index.js`* to *`main.js`* (and the `"bin":` entry in the package.json accordingly), `npx .` stop working.

What am I missing?

Is there some way to delete or updates old packages automatically installed in this way?

### EDIT

I found something in my home directory that could be interesting: if I run `npx .` with a debugger (blessed be the vscode debug terminal), I can follow the call stack discovering the path of the package!

in my case is `~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/`, and inside that folder I can find a pakage.json with only the "dependencies" entry expressed, and the single dependency expressed is my "foo" package

```
$ ls -l ~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 anto anto 4096 10 apr 11.34 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1 anto anto   75 10 apr 11.34 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 anto anto  540 10 apr 11.34 package-lock.json

$ cat ~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/package.json 
{
  "dependencies": {
    "foo": "file:../../../Projects/test-npm"
  }
}

$ ls -l ~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/node_modules/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 anto anto 31 10 apr 11.34 foo -> ../../../../Projects/test-npm
```

However this does not answer my question: why if I change the file name from index.js to main.js (and the package.json accordingly) the package is broken even if `~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/node_modules/foo` is a symlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it mostly figured out I think :)

npx will cache packages in `~/.npm/_npx`. And if it finds the package it's trying to execute it will use the info in its cache instead of trying to download (or use the local file).

In your case, if you look inside `~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/package-lock.json` you'll notice that it still has `bin` pointing to your old file (`index.js` in your case)

You'll also have `~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/.bin/` with a dead link inside. And finally `~/.npm/_npx/0b61241d7c17bcbb/.package-lock.json` also with your old filename.

Delete the cache directory and it will start working again.